# how to add custom filters to ng-table-dynamic?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have an Angular 1.6 app that uses ngTable (ng-table-dynamic). It works well, but I cannot figure out a way to add basic filters to the rows. I'm moving from `ng-table` to `ng-table-dynamic`
From:

```
%table{ng-table: "$ctrl.tableParams"}
    %tr{ng-repeat: "unit in $data track by unit.id"}
        %td{data-title: "'name'", sortable: "'name'"}
            {{unit.name}}
        %td{data-title: "'cost'", sortable: "'cost'"}
            {{unit.cost | currency:"$":0}}
```

to:

```
%table{ng-table-dynamic: "$ctrl.tableParams with $ctrl.columns"}
    %tr{ng-repeat: "unit in $data track by unit.id"}
        %td{ng-repeat: "col in $columns"}
            {{unit[col.field]}}
```

Any ideas on how to get that currency filter to apply for `ng-table-dynamic`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to web dev and can barely use HTML -- not sure where %table fits into all this, but in my ng-table-dynamic I have a tag: show-filter="true"

    <table ng-table-dynamic="params with properties" class="table table-striped table-hover" show-filter="true">

Comment: `%table` is HAML syntax.